# Working with multiple guards on a route file

Tags: angular

Please, I’m having some issues on my routes.
When the app starts (http://localhost:4200), its default is to go to the login page, and after a successful authentication, it navigates to the dashboard (http://localhost:4200/dashboard).
Now, I have a method to always check if the user is logged in or not.
If the user manually enters => http://localhost:4200 , I want it to redirect back to the dashboard since the method I used to track the user tells me the user is still logged in. Users are not able to activate children components if not logged in.
I have setup guards to protect my routes as shown below.

```
// Routes
export const routes: Routes = [ 
   { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: 'Login Page' },
     canActivate: [RedirectGuard] },
   { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
   { path: '', component: ChildrenLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Home' },
     runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
     canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     children: [
       {
          // Children component goes here
       }
     ]
   },
 ];

// RedirectGuard

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router) {}

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            return true;
        }
        // console.log('You shall not pass!');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Problem
I get a msg => Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. Base on my research, this shows that I’m having a loop on the route as per I placed RedirectGuard on LoginComponent. I have tried canLoad, but this does solve my issue still.
Please, any idea on how to achieve a situation whereby, if a user is logged in and visit http://localhost:4200 i.e empty route path, it should redirect me to dashboard.

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need a route like this:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    data: { title: 'Login Page' },
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard]
},
{
    path: '/login',
    // other settings but do not use authGuard or redirectGuard here
},
// ... other routes
```

Right now your RedirectGuard is sending users back to where they started (''), and so its a loop. You need a safe place to send them where it's okay to not be authenticated yet so they can get logged in, then when they hit root ('') again, they go to /dashboard. Also, instead of calling .navigate, you can actually return the urlTree instead.

```
canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return this.router.createUrlTree(['/dashboard']);
    }
    // console.log('You shall not pass!');
    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
}
```

Also, I could be mistaken, but this route will never be used since the first your first route will always resolve to it:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ChildrenLayoutComponent,
    data: { title: 'Home' },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            // Children component goes here
        }
    ]
},
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I've tried your recommendations, but the issue still persist.

Comment: Try creating a stackblitz example and posting it here. That'll give us something to tinker with and get working.